# Is a database right for me? Thousands of survey questions that go to a few people

Tags: database, excel, ms-access, sharepoint

I have been trying to research this problem but am not sure I'm looking at the right angles of the problem in order to start learning about a solution.

In order to meet requirements for Middle States accreditation at my college I have a 10,000-question survey currently in an Excel spreadsheet. Right now, we email the spreadsheet to survey respondents and they fill it out and email it back.

All the answers are either open-ended or numerical. The form currently includes some basic addition/multiplication formulas based on the numbers, and we show that to the respondents to help them fill out the survey.

In its current form, it's pretty much a nightmare to piece back together and work with. The major problem is with interfacing with the questions, moving things around, and moving from year to year with new data. The survey is updated and completed annually, but almost all of the questions stay the same.

Is a database with webforms the right thing to replace this with? I have looked into Microsoft Access and other database options but wonder if there is a more user friendly or simplistic solution. For example, should this just be done in an online survey platform like Qualtrics?

I've attached an example of what the survey  looks like, times 10,000.

Ever indebted to your advice or feedback on the problem.

```
1   How many desks are your in your office? →   Person A
2   How many people walk into your office every day?    →   Person A
3   [Multiply 1 x 2, show answer to survey respondent]  →   Person A
4   Based on the value produced in 3, do you think you have enough desks?   →   Person A
5   How many lamps are in your office?  →   Person B
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Google Forms and emailing the links.  It facilitates analyzing the survey results.

Answer (score 0):

Access is not the right choice for your case. Cause you would need to provide a central database and the client databases for connecting to this database.

Sharepoint could be a very easy to do this, if you are already using Sharepoint. SharePoint Survey function would the way to go.

Excel could also be used. I had a similar situation years ago. I put all the sheets in one folder and created a new excel file with a VBA script. this script read all the files in this particular folder and read all the survey results and put them together in my excel sheet as a resultset.